# Django with ngrok on Shopify

Tags: django, shopify, ngrok

I'm trying to get json data about orders from Shopify. The 'manage private apps' options seem to have changed in the last year or so and the last tut I can find for integrating with django seems out of date.

The Shopify private app tut for Ruby uses ngrok to establish a tunneling protocol and connect the local environment with the webhook, but I'm not sure how to use the ngrok proxy url in Django?

ngrok is running fine and I have the .ngrok.io url pointed at port 8000

I need to somehow pass a url in the format 
`https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json` 
to the ngrok proxy. How would I do that with Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would use ngrok for

- receiving webhooks from shopify as shopify will push webhooks to HTTPS enabled endpoints only.
- Developing public app

if you want to call any shopify API, you don't need ngrok tunnel.

`https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json` format is for private apps

Just make a request to `https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/orders.json` using your python script to get orders from shopify.

Comment: Ok this has helped enormously now I realise I don't need ngrok. I have also discovered I should use a get instead of post and the response is an object. So all working now!